# Send file to GitLab REST API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, gitlab, fetch-api

I'm trying to upload file with Gitlab API and everything is working correctly. I'm using the curl command with the terminal like:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: my-private-token" \
     --upload-file "path to"/file \
     "https://my-gitlab-url.it/api/v4/projects/<projectID>/packages/generic/<name_packaged>/<version>/<file>"
```

Now, because the curl via command line is a bit sketchy for "normal user", I'm developing a GUI to upload the file.

I have created a File Input Form with Boostrap with the code

```
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Chose the file</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" />
        </div>
```

And the javascript that read the data

```
var select_file = document.getElementById("formFile");
function onChangeSelectFile() {
  var value = select_file.files;
  var text = select_file.files[0].name;
  console.log(value, text);
}
select_file.onchange = onChangeSelectFile;
```

Now, I would like to use `fetch` with

```
fetch("https://my-gitlab-url.it/api/v4/projects/<projectID>/packages/generic/<name_packaged>/<version>/<file>", {
  headers: {
    "PRIVATE-TOKEN": "my-private-token",
  },
})
```

Clearly I miss the part where I send the actual file and I can't find a way to do it.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/) is a `PUT` request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it really was a `PUT` request:

```
fetch(file_string, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "PRIVATE-TOKEN": "my-private-token",
        },
        body: formData,
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("File uploaded successfully:", data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
        });
    }
```

where

```
var select_file = document.getElementById("formFile").files[0];
formData.append("file", select_file);
```